# django javascript template conditional test

Tags: javascript, html, django, templates, setattribute

I am looking to do conditional tests in the html part of my code

html

```
<p class= "rep3" width="100" id="val1" data1={{ family  }} style= "display:none;">{{ family }}</p>
<p class= "rep4" width="100" id="val2" data2="" style= "display:none;"></p>
{% if data2 == "general" %}
<a href="/one_category/all/">criteria1</a>
{% else  %}
{% if data2 == "ceramic" %}
<a href="/one_category/ceramic/">criteria2</a>
{% else  %}
<a href="/image3/">criteria</a>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

 var element = document.getElementById('val1');
laval1 =  element.getAttribute('data1');

var element2 = document.getElementById('val2');
element2.setAttribute('data2', laval1);

 });

</script>
```

I read data1 in the script
I would like to send this data in data2 and after to do the test
but its not working

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't work because:

- JavaScript code is run by the client, long after the template tags ({% if data2 == "general" %} etc. ) are compiled in the server.
- You can't send data from JS to django like that for data2. (Although you could use AJAX), but that is not required in this case.

Why don't you could do something like this, instead of relying on Javascript?

```
<p class= "rep3" width="100" id="val1" data1={{ family  }} style= "display:none;">{{ family }}</p>
<p class= "rep4" width="100" id="val2" data2="" style= "display:none;"></p>
{% if family == "general" %}
<a href="/one_category/all/">criteria1</a>
{% else  %}
{% if family == "ceramic" %}
<a href="/one_category/ceramic/">criteria2</a>
{% else  %}
<a href="/image3/">criteria</a>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```